# EF-Migrations Build Failed Due To NPM

Tags: c#, visual-studio, npm, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to update my database through migrations via Visual Studio in my package manager console I run

`Update-Database`

I'm getting an error:

> Build failed.

The only errors I have in my console are some BS NPM Errors.  I'd like to ignore the npm build for migrations.

Is there a way I can temporarily disable NPM Build, or ignore client errors from visual studio so Migrations can run properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a hacky way to do so:

Inside the CSProj File I can disable Npm build by commenting out this line

```
<Target Name="AngularBuild" AfterTargets="Build">
  <!--<Exec Command="npm run build" />-->
</Target>
```

This is not an ideal solution Id prefer to figure out how to do so through the IDE but it works for now.

(If anyone has a better solution I'll accept their answer)